# how to add uri of lexicon file in xml

Tags: c#, xml, lexicon

I am writing code for custom grammar for that I created a lexicon file which I am using in XML grammar file. I want to add the lexicon with my software to the end user as an embedded resources so how can i reference it's uri in XML?
my XML codes are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<grammar
  version="1.0" mode="voice" root="Voice_Automator"
  xml:lang="en-IN" tag-format="semantics/1.0"
  sapi:alphabet="x-microsoft-ups"
  xml:base="http://www.contoso.com/"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar"
  xmlns:sapi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Speech/2002/06/SRGSExtensions">
  **<lexicon uri="C:\Users\Agrawal\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\123.pls" />**
```

i want to use 123.pls file as an embedded resource so at the end user the program should load it properly

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the XML link mechanisms:

- [XLink](http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink/)

  ```
  <lexicon xmlns:link="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="C:\Users\Agrawal\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\123.pls"/>
  ```
- [External Entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-external-ent)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE foo [<!ENTITY bar SYSTEM "C:\Users\Agrawal\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\123.pls"> ]>
  <grammar  version="1.0" mode="voice" root="Voice_Automator"  xml:lang="en-IN" tag-format="semantics/1.0"  sapi:alphabet="x-microsoft-ups"  xml:base="http://www.contoso.com/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar"  xmlns:sapi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Speech/2002/06/SRGSExtensions">
  <? &bar; ?>
  </grammar>
  ```

**References**

- [XML Linking Language](http://xml.coverpages.org/xll.html)
- [XML Linking and Style](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-link-style/)
- [XML: How to read one file into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810486/1113772)
- [XML: How to load the contents of one xml file into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821567/1113772)
- [How do I check for the existence of an external file with XSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917655/1113772)
- [how to use xpointer to link to specific node from another document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550561/1113772)
- [Generate HTML / Help files from VS 2010 C# XML documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781784/1113772)